# Where did org.apache.cassandra.auth.Auth go in Cassandra 3?

Tags: java, cassandra

We have an authenticator implementation which was made for Cassandra 2.1. There, we used `org.apache.cassandra.auth.Auth#isSuperuser()` method to see whether the user is superuser or not.

In Cassandra 3 (namely 3.11.2), there is no `org.apache.cassandra.auth.Auth` class, and I could not find any `isSuperuser()` static method in it.

Is it still possible to achieve the same goal (determine whether a user is a superuser or not)? If not, what is the correct way to do it in Cassandra 3?

The artifact I'm using is `cassandra-all`.

Comment: Did you check IRoleManager interface? There is a isSuper method https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/auth/IRoleManager.java. You could implement this one with your own logic, add the compiled jar to the CLASSPATH in cassandra.in.sh and specify your class in cassandra.yaml file.

Comment: @Horia thank you, but what I need is other way around: I need to detect whether a user is a superuser *from the point of view of the standard Cassandra authentication*, and if so, use a different authentication method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be easy:

```
new AuthenticatedUser(username).isSuper()
```

This determines whether the user with login `username` is a superuser.